# C# nameof operator not work in Release configuration

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core-2.2

Recently i used `nameof` operator do determine name of null argument of a method and throw `ArgumentNullException`. But when i build my solution with `--configuration=Release` the log of exception was this:
[image]

my parameter name was something like `apiModel` and the exception was `throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(apiModel));` but, you can see result. Even stacktrace is only for first and second functions, not deeper in below layers, and i know this is because of optimization. But [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) said that `nameof` is resolved in compile time and i think my parameter name should be `apiModel` not the letter `s`. Am i doing something wrong??

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting your exception thrown earlier than you expect? Are you sure that your `throw` line is getting called?

Comment: Do you use code obfuscation?  If so it might have renamed your parameter.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: This error was for September 17th. I checked out project to commits of those days, and tried to reproduce this error. It seems there was a `s` variable somewhere in code flow, and that becomes null. So documents (as always) are right about `nameof` operator. Thanks for comments.